# How to read the calibration in a line profile

Tags: dm-script

I would like to read the calibration factor of a line profile. It is stored in "Image Display Info - Calibration". I use the function GetUnitsH (image, num), but I only obtain the channel number, not the calibrated position (in nanometers).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are seeking are:

```
Number ImageGetDimensionScale( BasicImage, Number dimension )
Number ImageGetDimensionOrigin( BasicImage, Number dimension )
String ImageGetDimensionUnitString( BasicImage, Number dimension )

Number ImageGetIntensityScale( BasicImage )
Number ImageGetIntensityOrigin( BasicImage )
String ImageGetIntensityUnitString( Number dimension )
```

These will give you the calibrations as shown in the image-display.

[image]

In order to convert *calibrated* and *uncalibrated* units, you have to do the accordign maths yourself.

And yes, each of the "Get" commands has an according "Set" command as well, if you need it.

---

One thing to watch out for is:

> Do you really look at your image, or at a *copy* of it?
>   In particular, makes sure that you use `:=` and not `=` when assigning image variables to images.

Example: 
This will work:

```
Image img := GetFrontImage()
number scale_x = img.ImageGetDimensionScale(0)
Result("\n Scale X:" + scale_x )
```

This will *not* work:

```
Image img = GetFrontImage()
number scale_x = img.ImageGetDimensionScale(0)
Result("\n Scale X:" + scale_x )
```

In the second case, one *gets* the refernece to the front-most image, but the `=` will just *copy the values* (and not the calibrations or other meta data) into a *new* image.

Comment: Thank you again. But I dont get the correct value using these commands. I obtain the values:

Comment: Thank you again. But I dont get the correct value using these commands. I obtain: DimensionScale=1; DimensionOrigin=-0; DimensionUnitString=""; IntensityScale=1; IntensityOrigin=0; IntensutyUnitString="".  However, the values that appear in tje Image Display Info window are: DimensionScale=0.020128; DimensionOrigin=0; DimensionUnitString="nm"; IntensityScale=2.82918; IntensityOrigin=1689.920; IntensutyUnitString="e-"

Comment: ? The commands given above do not return the values you see in the respective fields of the image-display? That would be very strange (bug) indeed. Which GMS version are we speaking of? Is there a way you could make the file you are working with available for me? (Some download-link?) Is it a regular line-profile or anything special with it (imported etc.) ? Is it a line profile with only one "slice" or multiple slices? (Each has it's own calibration!)

Comment: @AngelLarrea Can you also join me in this chat room now (I have about 30min) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180529/dm-script-proflie-calibration

Comment: It is correct. The commands do no return the same values displayed in the “Image Display Info”
It is GMS 2.32.888.0 version. It is a regular line-profile, with only one slice,  obtained from one of my images.

I am using a Mac computer and I run Digital Micrograph under Windows7 (with Parallels software).

I can send you the Profile to test it.